# PlaceHolderView - how insert a Listview or Recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Has anyone used a PlaceHolderView lib?
https://github.com/janishar/PlaceHolderView

has anyone ever come across the problem of putting a ListView or RecyclerView book inside the PlaceHolderView custom item?

need to insert a listview or recyclerview in the blank space in the image below

[Exemple layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlmX1.png)